# CicleCi: Multi module project fails to resolve dependency

Tags: java, maven, circleci

I am trying to build a CircleCI build for my Maven multi-module project. The problem is, when building on circle-ci, module B is not able to find dependnecy on module A.

If I check logs, module A is getting build fail. The problem here is, CircleCI is looking for `A.jar` on Maven Central Repo. It should be locally available as it is a maven sub-module.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project post-processor: 
Could not resolve dependencies for `B`: Could not find artifact 
A:1.1-snapshot in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: You defined a module which is not in the reactor.

Answer (score -1):

In project Settings -> dependency commands -> dependency overrides 
use mvn install